# Unable to reset the password of users in postgres

Tags: postgresql, authentication

Evrytime i run, `su - postgres` it asks me for a password which I did not set. I simply installed the postgres. I have gone to the pg_hba.conf.

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                               trust

# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

I changed the postgres method from `ident` to `trust` and then ran `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`. Even then it continues to ask for password. i am not sure where am I going wrong?

What should I do?

Comment: The password prompt when running `su` is done by the operating system **not** by Postgres.

Comment: so is the password of the operating system??

Comment: It is the password of the `postgres` user in the OS. if you're a sudoer, you can `sudo su - postgres`. If you're not a sudoer then you probably shouldn't be attempting this anyway. Also, you should revert the changes that you made in you `pg_hba.conf` file.

Comment: ya i am sudoer and i wish to remove that password of the postgres, for which i changed the method from ident to trust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the issue thanks to this site,

http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2009/06/postgresql-how-to-reset-user-name.html